# mongo-connector does not synchronize MongoDB ReferenceField fields to Elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, elasticsearch, indexing, config

I have the following dockerized setup tagged latest:

```
+---------+    +-----------------+    +---------------+
| MongoDB |––––| mongo-connector |––––| Elasticsearch |
+---------+    +-----------------+    +---------------+
```

I have configured the mongo-connector as follows:

```
{
   "mainAddress": "mongodb://mongodb:27017",
   "oplogFile": "/var/log/mongo-connector/oplog.timestamp",
   "noDump": false,
   "batchSize": -1,
   "verbosity": 2,
   "continueOnError": false,
   "namespaces": {
      "db.language": true,
      "db.tag": {
         "includeFields": ["name"]
      },
      "db.blogpost": {
         "includeFields": ["name", "content", "languages", "tags.name"]
      },
      "db.user": {
         "includeFields": ["username", "description"]
      },
      "db.comment": {
         "includeFields": ["text"]
      }
   },
   "logging": {
      "type": "file",
      "filename": "/var/log/mongo-connector/mongo-connector.log",
      "format": "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s:%(lineno)d - %(message)s",
      "rotationWhen": "D",
      "rotationInterval": 1,
      "rotationBackups": 10
   },
   "docManagers": [
      {
         "docManager": "elastic2_doc_manager",
         "targetURL": "elasticsearch:9200"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, mongo-connector is supposed to keep Elasticsearch in-sync with the MongoDB. So far, it all works out quite nicely. However, I am experiencing an issue with the namespaces nested fields. In the example given in the config it is with tags.name. `tag` itself is a collection as you can see from the config.

In my python code, the tags in the blogpost collection are implemented as `tags = ListField(ReferenceField('Tag'))`.

**The problem** is that there are no tag names in the elasticsearch index. I am not quite sure if this problem is due to the nature of the ReferenceField because the ReferenceField does merely store the ObjectId.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

- I am not quite sure how to proceed from this point.
- I would like to have a solution that requires me to change the config.

---

Things I've tested so far:

I changed `"tags.name"` to `"tags"` in the config to end up with a list of ObjectIds. This finding corroborates my belief about the nature of ReferenceField and how it does contribute to this problem.

Comment: FYI I also posted it here: https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/issues/682